# Change text onApproval Workflow

Tags: 2010, workflow, approval

Using approval workflow 2010 I want to change the text "Approval Started By `XXXX on 6/9/2017 2:02 PM"` to something else. How can I do this?

[image]

Comment: For new tasks or a specific task already approved!

Comment: For new tasks, this text is sent by email to the approver.